# Mapping relation nodes or way nodes to lat/lon coordinates?

Tags: polygon, openstreetmap, geotag

The goal is to construct a data structure that takes the id of a node/way/relation and returns the pair of lat/lon or the collection of lat/lon coordinates assigned to it.
So far, I have downloaded the osm file of my city, gotten rid of superfluous nodes like those pointing to amenities, and then used osmconvert with the all-to-nodes feature to construct a csv file that contains the columns @Id@name@lat@lon. This approach does work to construct a look up system for id(of node)->lat/lon. But not for id(of relation/way)--> List of lat/lons.
Does anybody know if there is a osmconvert feature or another way to retrieve this kind of list or csv file.

Comment: Ways and relations don't have coordinates itself. Only nodes have coordinates. If you want to obtain coordinates for ways and relations you have to look at all of their nodes.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do with osmconvert or osmfilter, collect the list  of nodes that are bundled together as a relations, retrieve their center points and return them as a list of lat/lons. The information is all there in the osm file so there must be a way to not do it manually.

Comment: Duplicate post: https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=62512